# i want to share a text message on facebook .how i can share message on facebook using angular or nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to share a text message on Facebook .how i can share message on Facebook using angular or NodeJs

I want result in angular or Nodejs code or Tuturial. I have a task that can contain Title,Description and date know I want to share as a post on Facebook.

Comment: Check Help Center [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then use google, first hit: [Posting on a Facebook Page Using Angular/nodeJS with Facebook Graph Api](https://nour-karoui.medium.com/posting-on-a-facebook-page-using-angular-nodejs-with-facebook-graph-api-fcd30453b03f)